# is there any function for removing bins of existing records using python client

Tags: python, aerospike

I want to remove bins from existing aerospike records. 
Is there any python client function which will be used to remove bins from existing records?

I tried with scanning entire set and update that record bin with `aerospike.null()` but it requires all records to scan.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove bins from individual records, pgupta's suggestions will work. If you want to remove bins from many records, a whole set, or a whole namespace, you can use a scan and [scan.execute_background()](https://aerospike-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scan.html#aerospike.Scan.execute_background) to remove bins the asynchronously. Below is an example of removing bins using a scan.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import aerospike
from aerospike_helpers.operations import operations
import time

# Configure the client.
config = {"hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 3000)]}

# Create a client and connect it to the cluster.
client = aerospike.client(config).connect()

TEST_NS = "test"
TEST_SET = "demo"

# Write the records.
keys = [(TEST_NS, TEST_SET, i) for i in range(5)]
for i, key in enumerate(keys):
    client.put(key, {"account_number": i, "score": i * 10})

# EXAMPLE: Remove score bin from each record.
ops = [operations.write("score", aerospike.null())]
scan = client.scan(TEST_NS, TEST_SET)
scan.add_ops(ops)
scan.execute_background()

# Allow scan to complete.
while True:
    response = client.job_info(job_id, aerospike.JOB_SCAN)
    if response['status'] != aerospike.JOB_STATUS_INPROGRESS:
        break
    time.sleep(0.1)

# Print bins.
for key in keys:
    _, _, bins = client.get(key)
    print(bins)

# Cleanup and close the connection to the Aerospike cluster.
for i, key in enumerate(keys):
    client.remove(key)
client.close()

"""
EXPECTED OUTPUT:
{'account_number': 0}
{'account_number': 1}
{'account_number': 2}
{'account_number': 3}
{'account_number': 4}
"""
```

If you want to limit which record's bins are removed, you can attach predicates to the scan. See the example at the bottom of [results()](https://aerospike-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scan.html#aerospike.Scan.results).

Answer (score 1):

Update the bin of the record, setting it to null using put() and aerospike.null() or use remove_bin to remove one or more bins.

API reference here: https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html?highlight=bin#aerospike.Client.remove_bin